# Android in-app purchases for ad free version

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Hi can someone point me in the right direction to implement an in-app purchase to unlock the ad free version on android apps?

Comment: What platform/language is your app written in/on?

Comment: I believe his topic has mentioned that it is for Android

Answer (score 1):

You should check these:

[In app billing overview](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html)

[Implementing In-app Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)

Alternatively, you may create a paid app simply as an authenticator, and communicate with the the free app and the paid authenticator, with your own protocol.

These two methods provides different advantages.

Comment: Thanks derek i will have a look through the linka and get back.

Comment: Ok ive found something on non consumable items here: developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume . Now i need to find an example of this.